# Docker + Django - Make SQLite3 database really persistent

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I want to make my SQLite3 database persistent even if I would run commands like `docker compose down` `stop` `start` `up` and `build`.

This is my setup:

**Dockerfile_DEV:**

```
# Base image
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the entire project directory
COPY . /app

# Install project dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements_dev.txt

# Expose port
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the development server
CMD ["python", "doc_manager/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**docker-compose-DEV.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_DEV
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/doc-manager-web
      - data:/app/doc-manager-web/data
    
volumes:
  data:
```

**Directory tree:**

```
doc-manager-web  # Main project's folder (in here there's also Dockerfile_DEV and docker-compose-DEV.yml)
├───data  # Folder containing my SQLite3 database file
├───documentation
└───doc_manager  # Django project
    ├───core
    │   ├───migrations
    │   │   └───__pycache__
    │   ├───templates
    │   │   └───core
    │   └───__pycache__
    ├───doc_manager
    │   └───__pycache__
    └───media
        └───documents
```

Even though I have set up the `volume` in my docker-compose-DEV.yml file, it does not seem to work. The SQLite3 database will always get rolled back to it's initial state whenever I try to run `docker compose down` and then `docker compose up`.

What should I do to make it really persistent so that I can re-build and re-deploy my whole Django project using Docker whenever I make some code changes but without any changes done to the SQLite3 database file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image's `WORKDIR` is set to `/app`.  If your SQLite database is in a `data` subdirectory, it will be in `/app/data`.  You're actually mounting the `data` volume to a different directory; so in reality the SQLite database is being stored in the container temporary filesystem, and that's why you're seeing data be lost on container restarts.

You need to fix the `volumes:` so that the data volume is mounted on the correct directory.  Do not try to bind-mount the code into the container: it is already in the image, and you can get surprising results if the filesystem layout is substantially different between what's in the image and what's in the host system.

```yaml
volumes:
  - data:/app/data
  #      ^^^^^^^^^ not in a subdirectory that happens to match the host directory name
  # no bind mount of all of ./
```

You may need to make sure your code takes steps required to initialize the database if it does not exist, for example running SQL `CREATE TABLE` instructions.  Docker named volumes have special initialization behavior that no other volume type has.  If you try to run this in Kubernetes, or bind-mount a host directory, you will start off with an empty directory.  If your application framework has a migration system, that can be a good approach.

Comment: Interesting explanation, thank you. Could you please elaborate how is the ’WORKDIR` directive connected with volumes in this case? Also, I am not sure I understood how should I change my Dockerfile or docker-compose-DEV.yml exactly? Thank you

Comment: If you delete all of the `volumes:`, and you `docker-compose run web sh` and start looking around in an interactive shell, you can see the SQLite file should be in `/app/data`.  The right-hand side of `volumes:` needs to match the filesystem layout that's already in the image.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be indeed the case. Will try in the next few hours. In the meantime, I am accepting your answer.